# how to reference d3js object on hover and click

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am working with an existing piece of code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/e2kpAaMjTTzmXnE4ghGY?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>



<style>



.states {

  fill: none;

  stroke: #fff;

  stroke-linejoin: round;

}



 .county:hover {



    fill: red !important;

  }


svg:hover{

background: black;

}



</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="float:left,width:40%" id="click"></div>

 <!-- For Dropdown menu --> 

    <select onchange="Dropdown(this.value)">

      <option >Unemployeement</option>

      <option >Random</option>

    </select>

<script>

$("div").click(function(){

alert("here");

});

var width = 960,

    height = 500;



var color = d3.scale.threshold()

    .domain([0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.10])

    .range(["#f2f0f7", "#dadaeb", "#bcbddc", "#9e9ac8", "#756bb1", "#54278f"]);



var path = d3.geo.path();



var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")

    .attr("width", width)

    .attr("height", height);



queue()

    .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us.json")

    .defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv")

    .await(ready);



function ready(error, us, unemployment) {

  if (error) throw error;



  var rateById = {};



  unemployment.forEach(function(d) { rateById[d.id] = +d.rate; });



  svg.append("g")

      .attr("class", "counties")

    .selectAll("path")

      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)

    .enter().append("path")

      .attr("d", path)

        .attr("class", "county")

      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(rateById[d.id]);

      });    

  svg.append("path")

      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a.id !== b.id; }))

      .attr("class", "states")

      .attr("d", path);

 var object=svg.append("foreignobject");

 var div=object.append("div");

 var tooltip=d3.select("div").append("span")

 .attr("class","ccc")

 .style("z-index", "10")

    .style("visibility", "hidden")

    .style("position", "absolute")   

    .style("text-align","center")     

    .style("width","60px")          

    .style("height", "28px")         

    .style("padding","2px")       

    .style("font","12px sans-serif")    

    .style("background","lightsteelblue") 

    .style("border","0px")    

    .style("border-radius","8px")     

    .style("pointer-events","none") 

 .text("here");



d3.select("div") 

  .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})

  .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})

  .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});  

 $("span").click(function(){

    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");

});

}

var dropdownMap = {
  'Unemployeement': 'unemployment.tsv',
  'Random': 'random.tsv'
}

function Dropdown(val){

  let file = dropdownMap[val];

  if(!file){
    file = 'unemployment.tsv'
  }

    queue()

    .defer(d3.json,"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us.json")

    .defer(d3.tsv, file)

    .await(ready);

}

</script>

</body>



</html>
```

There's two areas I'm trying to repair.
1. the tooltip.  I've been able to get a hover over a particular county, but I don't know how to rectify which county I'm hovering.  in line 186, I have `.text("here");`.  I need that to be html `.text("<div id='countyid'>text</div>"`.  however, the tags show up as text, and I can't get the countyid referenced into the id field.

2.the click.  on line 74, I have an alert, based on the click.  I need to know which county I'm clicking on.  it appears I'm missing something that identifies the countyid.

how do I reference them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with d3.js, however with a little reading of the docs and some fiddling I made you a new [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V84uXPdRozhbzjjbtO2P?p=preview).

Your were binding all your tooltip and click events to your main `div`. I reworked your code and set the events to trigger on the "paths" that are the counties.

Each county now shows it's `id` when you mouse over it, the tooltip has the markup you wanted (the id of the div is the id of the county. I used the `id` instead of the word "text" as the content of the div) and when you click a county it alerts it's `id`.

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Add *mouseover* and *mouseclick* handlers associated with SVG bound to polygon data and use your tooltip definition from there. Note that you can pass hovered/clicked polygon to that callback. The `text()` called on `tooltip` is not needed. This is major change:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features) // us has list of polygons
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "county")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(rateById[d.id]);
    }).on("mouseover", function(county) {
        // change tooltip content here
        tooltip.html("County ID " + county.id); 
    }).on("click", function(county) {
        // define your on-click reaction here
        alert("County ID clicked " + county.id); 
    });
```

Working code is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/qHHczyK57H2QzNG6eIik?p=preview

Disclaimer: I have introduced minimal set of changes to your code (plus removed empty lines for readabilty) to address your issue. Any other issues your code may expose are left intact.

(PS: I should have posted partial answer before taking break ;)